# Particles in air

Tags: everyday-life, atmospheric-science, air

This is a strange question.
I can see particles in the air.They are not dust particles. They are smaller than a pin's point, and millions of them exist. If I put a pattern to them, the majority of them zoom down on a 90-degree angle from left to right and right to left. They bounce off each other, and then a random pattern is made throughout the angles. When they get close to a solid object, they hit it and bounce off, sometimes in a curve like water from a fountain, sometimes at a 90-degree angle. If I concentrate, I can see that the particle changes into a more seeable larger but still minuscule form.I can also see dust certain particles floating through the rigid patterns of their descent.
Please don't find me crazy, as I already feel it. I have asked many if they can see this too, but no one has said yes. I was in a fatal airplane crash at eight and a fatal car accident at 38. I think that I had recognized this in my teens, but I felt like everyone saw the same. what do you think this is? If you could enlighten me, I would be grateful.

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  I'm not sure that this question is really answerable in this forum; it's not clear that the phenomena you describe are due to the way your visual system works, due to [floaters](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/eye-floaters/symptoms-causes/syc-20372346), or something else.  So unfortunately I suspect this question is going to be closed as off-topic here.

Comment: A simple question "what do you see with your eyes closed? "

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to hear that you are suffering from this condition. I will make a couple of suggestions which I hope will help you.

if you are standing outside at night, do you see the glowing dots when looking straight ahead? if so, shine a flashlight in their direction. Do they become brighter, or not?

If you see them when looking straight ahead, note their pattern of movements and then look straight upwards. Does their pattern of movement change?. Then try tilting your head left and then right. Do they change?

Lie flat on the ground on your belly, and look forward and note the movement pattern. then roll over and look forward, so you are seeing things upside down. Does the pattern change?

If they do not become brighter, and if their movement pattern does not change, then you are not seeing anything like floating dust- you are detecting nerve impulses generated in your retinas, optic nerves, or the visual cortex inside your brain. This means you should see a doctor specializing in disorders or damage to the optic nerves or visual cortex.